# problem with main (Cumulative Layout Shift) after add google custom results page above it

Tags: blogger, shift

I will try my best to make it easy for you

I use **result only layout** for google custom search (engine) in my website
and that's mean I will use my own default search box or engine to show google results and that's okay
So, I put `<div class="gcse-searchresults-only"></div>` in HTML/JavaScript above the blog post gadgets where the results will appear as in the picture below
[image]
but the problem is that main (topic+labels) move to up and get back to its place everytime I refresh my websites or any page on my website
[image]
So, what should I do?
[my website url](https://ezzeddinisalm.blogspot.com/) if you want to test it

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[solved]

I added

```
.gsc-control-cse.gsc-control-cse-ar {
    padding: 0 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

to

```
<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=3a17cd22938848eef"></script>
<div class="gcse-searchresults-only"></div>
```

answered by **Eprahem Magdy**